# Docker Update hangs on Windows 10

Tags: docker

I have a docker 1.13.0 installed on my Windows 10. Two times per day there I see this window

[image]

I click install, it starts to update, at 5% it hangs. One time I ran it at the morning and till the evening it was still 5%.
Moreover, when you click cancel it hangs too.

Do you know the reason of it and how it can be updated without uninstall old and install new?

Comment: having the exact same problem on Windows 10. Were you able to get around the issue eventually?

Comment: No, I did not found any solution. Now I'm on mac and there is no problem for me anymore